# Css menu collapses when window is minimized

Tags: html, css, menu, web

I have a css menu that goes across the page and I have a few blocks that go across to, I want it so that when the window is minimized the menu just stays the same and doesnt minimize

[image]

is what it looks like when the window isnt minimized

[image]

is what happens when the page is minimized, I want it so that the menu just gets cut off and doesnt reform. Also I cant figure out how to make the menu blocks (Home, Standings...) to go to the center of the page, they stay on the side

here is my css code

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */


body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input,       textarea, blockquote {
margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;

}


body {
font-family: Brixton , sans-serif; font-size: 22px; line-height: 0px; 
// controls the text size, color, font
}

nav ul ul {
display: none;
//sets menu dislpay setting
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    //displays the block under the main tabs in the menu
}


nav ul {
background: #efefef; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
//change menu background
padding: 0 20px;
list-style: none;
position: relative;


}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    //displays the background
}

nav ul li {
     float:left;
     //decides which side the menu is on
}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #4b545f;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
        //changes the color of the menu when hovered over
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 25px 53px;

        color: #007FFF; text-decoration: none;
    }


nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: probably just need a width on the menu container

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to always be the same, then you'll need to specify a width on the nav element.

```
nav { width : 960px; }
```

That should stop it.